# Lambda function not exiting after Docker container exits

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a simple Python script inside a Docker container with a lambda function.

## Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
# .dockerignore should include .venv directories
COPY . /app/

# Install poetry with specified version
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_VERSION=1.5.1 POETRY_HOME=/etc/poetry python3 -

# Include Poetry's binaries in the PATH
ENV PATH="/etc/poetry/bin:${PATH}"

# Disable the creation of virtualenvs by poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

# Install project dependencies
RUN poetry install --no-interaction

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "/app/my_script.py"]
```

The container resulting from this script runs a Python program & uploads some data to an S3 bucket once completed. All of this works fine on lambda and locally. The average runtime is 2-3 seconds. When testing Lambda I've given a timeout of 5 minutes, on average it runs for 1 minute. I'm unsure why it isn't shutting down when the container exits. Here's the error message I'm getting.

```
START RequestId: 52d04952-5950-47d3-a64d-787285da8afc Version: $LATEST
RequestId: 52d04952-5950-47d3-a64d-787285da8afc Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: 52d04952-5950-47d3-a64d-787285da8afc
REPORT RequestId: 52d04952-5950-47d3-a64d-787285da8afc  Duration: 33365.48 ms   Billed Duration: 33366 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 121 MB
```